# sqlsrv PDO drivers not found

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am running PHP 5.6.31, and I am trying to download sqlsrv drivers.  I am updating my php.ini files.  I am putting the extension_dir correctly, and the files are in that directory.  I am putting the correct name in the php.ini for the extensions. However, when i run php --ini, I am getting this message

> %1 is not a valid Win32 Application

Does anyone have any suggestions.

Here is the image of the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Your question says you're using PHP 5.6, but your screenshot shows PHP 7.1. Which is correct? Are you on 32 bit Windows or 64 bit Windows?

Comment: When i do phpinfo(), at the top it says php 5.6.  When it loads the php.ini files, it is saved in the directory php7.1.9

Comment: Each PHP process uses a single version of PHP. It looks like you've got multiple versions of PHP installed (there's nothing fundamentally wrong with that) and you're trying to configure the wrong one. How did you install PHP?

Comment: Possibly you have two versions of PHP installed. What does `php --version` tell you? What does `where php` say? From the path and the filenames, it also looks like you're trying to use 32-bit sqlsrv drivers with a 64-bit PHP installation...

Comment: @Chris I installed PHP through WAMP/ it came with WAMP.

Comment: @MattGibson I did php --version and it says I am running PHP 7.2.3 (cli).  When i run where php, it says xammp\php\php.exe

Comment: So you're not running PHP 5.6.31, you're running 7.2.3. Where are you doing your phpinfo()? Is this in a web browser? PHP comes in both web and CLI flavours; it's possible you're running a different PHP on the command line than on your web server.

Comment: I am running phpinfo() from the localhost.  I found that WAMP was messing me up.  I have reinstalled WAMP, and was able to change the WAMP version from 5.6.31 to 7.1.9.  I also uninstalled my XAMMP directory so that does not interfere at all.  I ran both command line and web browser version and both are now running 7.1.9.

Comment: Okay. In that case all I think all you need to do is install the right architecture SQL Server driver, that is the x64 version, not the x86 one you seem to be using at the moment, to match your 64-bit WAMP.

Comment: I got the x64 version installed, and I changed the name in my php.ini, however i am an error that says "the specified module could not be found". These are the extensions that I am using extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll. I am still getting the same message

Comment: I changed the files to the ts version in the configuration file. When I run php -m, pdo_sqlsrv shows up, however when I run phpinfo(), under PDO, sqlsrv does not show up. I am getting the error, driver could not be found when I run my app.

Comment: Have you changed the correct configuration file? In your `phpinfo()` display, does it show that the path to the INI file is actually the one you changed?

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the extension from non-thread secure to thread secure files. After doing this, the sqlsrv drivers showed up in phpinfo()